# How to better use the "def" function and not give "<function test_message at 0x7f5d198b3ca0>" error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
def test_message(ctx):
  ctx.send("testing")

@bot.command()
async def testa(ctx):
  await ctx.send(test_message)
```

I have this down to test the "def" function but when I call in inside a Discord chat it send, "<function test_message at 0x7f5d198b3ca0>" and not "testing". Could someone better explain how t set this up?

Comment: `"def"` is not a function, it is a keyword used to define a function. It's not really clear what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to simply send the message `"testing"`? Why not do so directly? If not, please provide more details.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to use the "def" or "async def" more. I'm making a function that creates a account for a user and I'm going to be using that function a lot.

Comment: It seems you're trying to send a single message here, but you're calling `ctx.send()` twice.  How can that be right?  There are a number of ways to fix your code.  All of them will involve removing one of the two `ctx.send()` calls.

Comment: It seems that you don't even know how regular functions work, learning async programming without even knowing the basics is a bad, bad idea. @JoeMomma

Comment: I didn't know the difference with "async def" amd "def". That's why I'm making tests.  And for me using the send function more than one time, I didn't know I could've only used it once. Beginner at work :thumbup:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.send` takes the object you pass it and makes a string out of it. For functions, you'll get that representation.

Instead, you'll want to make `test_message` an async function (so you can call async functions such as `ctx.send` within it) and just call it.

```
async def test_message(ctx):
  await ctx.send("testing")

@bot.command()
async def testa(ctx):
  await test_message(ctx)
```